# Trackman Marble scrolling for complete Linux/Lubuntu newbie

Tags: linux, logitech-mouse, lubuntu

I am brand new to Linux, like within 24 hours. I am just trying to set up my development environment. But I've burned 2-3 hours trying to just configure my Logitech Trackman Marble to work the way I've configured it for the last ten years. What I want is for the small left button to be held down and let me scroll down the page. I don't want it mapped to go back like is set by default.

I found these links:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Logitech_Marblemouse_USB
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Logitech_Marble_Mouse

The second one in particular seems so straightforward. But I'm stuck at steps one and two. I don't know how to install `xf86-input-libinput`. I don't know how to edit a configuration file. I did find the `sudo nano` command, but I'm pretty sure I overwrote both by 10-libinput.conf and 40-libinput.conf files rather than append to them. So who knows what consequences that will have?

My Windows machine was running like garbage so I installed Lubuntu to give it new life. It does indeed fly now, but I've spent probably six hours just trying to set up a basic development environment and every single step is painstaking.

Immediate help with my Trackman Marble problem would be great, but more importantly, if anyone has a video tutorial showing how Linux actually works for beginners, I could not be more grateful.

Edit: I almost lost this entire question because I'm so used to scrolling with a particular button that is now mapped to go back. Driving me absolutely bonkers.

Comment: First off Arch and Lubuntu are *very* different.  I highly doubt the directions for Arch will work with Lubuntu, as they use different desktop environments.  Secondly, as for a video tutorial, there are *counless* tutorials on YouTube.  Have you tried the first set of instructions?

Comment: There are many text editors available for Linux.  They vary in power, complexity, and ease of use.  (Generally the more powerful ones are more complex and therefore hard to use, or at least harder to learn.)  Pick one (for starters) and *learn* it  before you start using it on important files.